# How to generate file inside the container that has the same permissions as my local user?

Tags: docker

Whenever I generate a file inside the php container, this file is root, I always need to give chmod -R 777 to be able to edit and this is very annoying, for example, my user is rafaelconceicao and inside the container the permissions are for root and one user that is a sequence of numbers 296823135, whenever I generate a new file, it remains the root permission, making it impossible for me to do the editing. What should I do?
(My system is Fedora 27)

My docker files are here: https://github.com/junta1/gfp/tree/develop

I created it from: https://phpdocker.io/generator

Answer (score 0):

The issue discussed in [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3124).

By default a container starts with user root unless you explicity specify the user. But not that some Docker images expect to be running with root user inside and thus starting them with another user won't work.

The problem is that a root user inside the container, will be root outside the container. You might try to start the container with a custom user in the compose file: `user: 1000 /path/to/mount`.

That might not work if the Docker image expects a root user. In that case you need to exec into the container using `docker exec -it <container-name> bash` and run `chown -R <your-uid>:<you-uid>`

Comment: I found these solutions, access the container with the same privileges as my local user and give it permission in the project for the same privileges as my crazy user.

Access container:

docker exec -it -u $ (id -u): $ (id -g) CONTAINER_NAME bash

Giving permission to your local user from outside the container.

"sudo chown -R $ USER: $ USER."

Comment: Thank you for your help.